# Azure App Services not available on scheduled deployment but works with manual

Tags: azure, azure-devops, stackexchange.redis, azure-appservice

I am unsure if this is the right place for this question, however there is no other suitable alternative that I can think of to ask in the stack communities.

I have a number of Azure App Services that are deployed via Azure DevOps (ADO). When I deploy this manually, everything works fine.

API talks to API, API talks to Redis Cache

When this is automatically deployed over night, the deployment happens the same, all goes through ok however,

API talks to API, API cannot talk to Redis Cache.

The only thing that appears to work is to reboot the cache and redeploy the ADO Artefact manually again.  Rebooting the API App Services do not have an impact.

The exceptions being thrown are `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` with Failed method `StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed`

exception thrown

> No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL; An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. SocketFailure on xxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Subscription, origin: EndReading, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 52s ago, last-write: 52s ago, unanswered-write: 534604s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: ConnectedEstablished, in: 0, ar: 0, last-heartbeat: 0s ago, last-mbeat: 0s ago, global: 0s ago One or more errors occurred. (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..) Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

The thing I dont understand is why it works with a manual deployment and does not with an automatic \ scheduled deployment